# ¿Cómo extraer por separado los valores de una consulta de mysql por medio de PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Muy buen día a todos, espero me puedan ayudar con la siguiente duda.

Tengo el siguiente arreglo el cual me muestra una fila con los datos solicitados:

```
<?php
include('php/conexion.php');

$res=$link->query("SELECT * FROM plantillas_laborales  WHERE email_asociado='$email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3")or die($link->error);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    
 printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["nombreemple"], $row["identificacionemple"]);

}

?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es extraer cada valor que me muestre la consulta y convertirlo en una variable con php, para luego estas mismas mostrarlas por separado en una página con HTML como la siguiente manera:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="empleados">
            <!--empleado 1-->
            <p><?php echo $nombre1; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $ide1; ?></p>
            <br>
            <!--empleado 2-->
            <p><?php echo $nombre2; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $ide2; ?></p>
            <br>
            <!--empleado 3-->
            <p><?php echo $nombre3; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $ide3; ?></p>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Leí por un foro que para extraer los valores de array es necesario utilizar los métodos de **array_keys()** y **array_values()**, pero estoy un poco perdido respecto a eso, no sé si alguien me pueda ayudar o comentarme un método más eficaz para hacer todo esto gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que el código te trae las filas esperadas, puedes construir el contenido dentro del `while`, por ejemplo:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
        include('php/conexion.php');
        $res=$link->query("SELECT * FROM plantillas_laborales  WHERE email_asociado='$email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3")or die($link->error);
        $html='<div class="empleados">';
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            $html.=sprintf("<p>%s</p><p>%s</p><hr />",$row["nombreemple"], $row["identificacionemple"]);
        }
        $html.='</div>';
        echo $html;
    ?>
    </body>    
</html>
```